# Swift iOS: How do I handle remote notification when app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

How do I handle a push remote notification when the app is not running. Currently, when remote notification comes in, and my app is in foreground or background, my code is correctly handling the remote notification. But when the app is not running, and remote notification come in, I see a remote banner on top of screen, and when I tapped on it, my app get launch and go away. It doesn't seem to handle the remote notification correctly. Is this how iOS behave, or is there a way to handle it. Thanks. This is currently my code in AppDelegate.swift.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{   
    ...
    println("..... application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()")


    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
    // there is a notification...do stuff...
    println("dinFInishLaunchingWithOption().. calling didREceiveRemoteNotification")
    self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteNotification as [NSObject : AnyObject])

    }
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    println("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")
}

fun application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)
{
    println(error)
    println(error.localizedDescription)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    println("..... application didReceiveRemoteNotification()")
}
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Implement the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` function. Be sure to call the completion handler.

Comment: Hi manddy, could u clarify what u mean by calling the completion handler. Thanks.

Comment: From the code, when remote notification come in and app is in terminate state, I  expected the code will hit didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  and call didReceiveRemoteNotification, but I don't see that happening in my testing. Thanks.